# How to search inside files on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-search, file-filter

In Windows XP we can search for files that contain a defined keyword (inside all files types).

Windows 7 can look inside files for a keyword, but only for text files. (`*.doc, *.txt, *.inf, ...`), not (`*.conf, *.dat, *.*, ...`).

[Microsoft search filters](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/Advanced-tips-for-searching-in-Windows) don't contain any filter I can use for this.

How is this possible?

Comment: Most of the answers below are useless and do not address the question that had been asked. The problem that the OP clearly explained was that Windows Vista+ do not search the contents of certain file types (read file **extensions**). As they clearly said, some work while others do not. For example, it will find `.txt` file that contain a word, but not `.cpp`, `.cfg`, `.php`, or even `.ini` files even though they are all plain-text (and `.ini` files are even standard to Windows!) This problem still exists and the simplest solution seems to be [this answer](http://superuser.com/a/374882/3279).

Comment: MS Visual Studio has a great "find in files" function. No setup - just specify the criteria for more or less instant results. Why this is not in Windows Explorer as an "Advanced" option is beyond me.

Answer (score 132, accepted):

To get to the **Indexing Options**:

Start --> Control Panel --> Indexing Options

See [Change advanced indexing options](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows7/change-advanced-indexing-options) for more information.

If you click on the **Advanced** button in [Indexing Options](http://www.windows7update.com/Windows7-Indexing-Options.html) and go to the **File Types** tab, you will get a list of file types and the way they are indexed. For the file types you want, you can specify that you want the file contents indexed, and not just the file properties.

Or you can just do a normal search, and after the search is finished you can click on the "File Contents" button under the "Search again in" field (which is located after the end of the search results list, if you scroll to the bottom).

Based on [this page](http://www.windows-noob.com/forums/index.php?/topic/1532-windows-explorer-search-no-file-content-in-search-again-in/), the "File Contents" option won't always show up - only when the folder being searched is not marked for file content indexing; in that case, file contents are supposedly searched automatically, without having to specify this option explicitly.

Comment: Or maybe by using the the FIND command instead.

Comment: @Revolter, do you mean the command-line command FIND? That only searches for a string in a single, specified file; it does not list files that contain said string.

Comment: @Synetech inc. - you can pipe the results of another command into `find`, so there's no reason you couldn't run it on the entirety of the hard drive (maybe using an `attrib` search)

Comment: @Synetechinc. You can say: `find "word" *`

Comment: Hmm, I guess using computers since the old days has the distinct disadvantage that it becomes harder to learn about the updates to old commands unless you purposely do so. (It’s not the first time that I’ve learned of new functionality to an old DOS command long after everyone else, including people who learned them in Windows. `:-|`)

Comment: @nikhil: Unfortunately you don't mention how to get to Indexing Options, nor does the page you link to.

Comment: @Steve it's an item in the Control Panel. You can also find it by typing it in the search field on the Start menu.

Comment: @Nikhil, is there a way to search within files in unindexed locations as well?

Comment: -1 as it doesn't search in non-indexed locations, even when the option is selected. @[Shimmy](http://superuser.com/users/9825/shimmy) Sean's answer below does.

Comment: @HaydnWVN it should check non-indexed locations. Seans answer doesn't work for some people either...

Comment: I don’t use the indexer, so this does NOT fix anything.

Comment: Using Powershell (I like because I can use full regex): Get-ChildItem -recurse *.config | Select-String -pattern "mystring" | group path | select name

Comment: Created a short video to demo how to apply the solution in this answer http://bit.ly/2p15Ipp

Comment: Far too complicated. Windows Explorer needs an "Advanced" button which hooks to the "Find in Files" function already available in MS Visual Studio. No setup, just immediate results.

Answer (score 113):

I've always gotten better performance when searching inside files by using a GREP tool. I'm a fan of [AstroGrep](http://astrogrep.sourceforge.net).

Comment: AstroGrep is lean & mean. 80k, lightning fast, & searches network locations. Thanks for the heads up on this tool.

Comment: Wow!! this one is good!

Comment: Also a plug here for Agent Ransack. Shell integrated, small and fast, supports regex as well.

Comment: [grepWin](http://stefanstools.sourceforge.net/grepWin.html) is a similarly lightweight grep tool for Windows that has different options  from AstroGrep that are useful in some situations.

Comment: Awesome tool! Thank you! The Windows search within files is piece of..., well you know.
This tool is super fast on my SAS drive and works flawlessly. Found over 200 files where the windows search within contents found only 12 and didn't display what I've been searching for, but I knew what I search and I was certain for the directory.
Should I say more?

Thanks again!

Comment: +1 for AstroGREP and +1 for AgentRansack... +1 also for Cygwin grep command line tool...

Comment: Tried AstroGrep and it seems nice, but I needed to find text inside MS Word files with extension .docx, and it seems to exclude these by default.  With no way to override!

Answer (score 84):

I believe you can also just enter "content:blahblah" in the search filter box in upper right corner of Windows Explorer.  This works at least for Text files and Office documents. It also works for source files.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work

Comment: @ThomasMcLeod working to me, maybe you need the "searching in nonindexed files"

Comment: For Windows 7 it looks like it's content: not contents:

Comment: I found that it is also localized, in German for example `inhalt:`

Comment: 'contents:$$$' where $$$ is the content i'm looking for works for me in Windows 7

Comment: It looks like SP1 ignores content: and contents: now, even though it still turns blue; instead you have to click File Contents at the bottom of the search results.

Comment: Doesn't work in Windows 7 32 bit. I copied and pasted from a file in the directory being searched and it said that string wasn't found.

Comment: The "content:blahblah" tip worked well for me. We've got a folder containing a bunch of SQL queries and we're constantly using Notepad++ to search the contents of that directory for certain keywords, table names, etc. This search keyword eliminates the need for that step. [Note: it was the singular form — content vs. contents — that worked for me in Windows 10.]

Comment: It seems to work for html, js, css, xml, sql, but unfortunately **not** php.

Comment: The field is irrelevant, both `content:` and `contents:` work, but only on certain file types like `.txt` and `.html`. The problem is that it does NOT work for other types of plain-text files like `.cpp`, `.php`, `.cfg`, or for that matter, even `.ini` which is type that comes with Windows.

Comment: This only works with a few predefined file types. I does not work with .tex files, which I'm sure have been known as easy to search through, text-only files for decades. It's not even possible to force the search to look at these files (`*.tex content:begin`), quite ridiculous.

Answer (score 57):

You can play with [findstr](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490907.aspx).

```
findstr /s /m searchstring *.*
```

Options description:

```
/S         Searches for matching files in the current directory and all subdirectories.
/M         Prints only the filename if a file contains a match.
```

Comment: @Synetech Why not? It's very easy to use, e.g. `findstr "todo" *.txt`.

Comment: /i for case insensitivity is also potentially very valuable.

FINDSTR is the only, ONLY non third party way I have found to search for PARTIAL strings. If you search for

goog

it will match google.com or 123779goog44682 or 123google.com55

and to my knowledge there is NO way the Windows folder/Explorer "search box" or Control-F can perform that very, very simple, logical task. Speaking after decades of high end C and Assembler computer development work, laugh or mock all you want, but I state to you: imbecilic Microsoft designers *do not understand computers.*

Answer (score 18):

Notepad++ can do this and is free. Find in files is <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd>.

Answer (score 15):

[Agent Ransack](http://www.mythicsoft.com/agentransack/) is always worth a look. It's free, fast, good reputation, and doesn't use indexing.

Comment: Note - I had been using AR but there are some licensing restrictions about personal vs business use.  Overall though the tool works really well and give the kind of file search focus one needs.

Answer (score 9):

In Windows Explorer, menu Tools -> Folder Options:

Press on the search tab and here, the first option: *what to search*, choose to search for non-indexed files inside the file.

Comment: This seemed to ignore the option, because my file type was configured in the Index Options to not be treated as a text file. A `.properties` file does not get searched for text by default.

Comment: This was the only answer on this page that worked for me. I had to check the "Don't use the index when searching..." option, too.

Comment: Not using the indexer, so this does not fix the problem.

Answer (score 8):

Windows 7 still has the ability to search for strings inside files everywhere (and not in indexed locations).

In Windows Explorer, go to menu Tools/Folder options and select "Always search file names and contents".

Probably the file types still have to be set up correctly in Advanced Options of Indexing Options".

Comment: +1 for the Indexing Options. These are VERY IMPORTANT because they define what Windows means by "searching" a file. e.g. I have an ANT build script `.properties` file that Windows would not search because it wasn't configured to treat it as a text file.

Comment: Odd that indexing options affect non-indexed searches.

Comment: Yes, the types are the problem, so this answer would have been better if it hadn’t ended just before mentioning the fix.

Comment: In Windows 10 that option is in menu *View* → *Options* → *Change folder and search options* → tab *Search*.

Comment: @Peter Mortensen, or equivalently in _File → Change folder and search options → Search_. :-)

Answer (score 6):

The answer by Sean Sexton gave me what I was looking for (putting "content:" in the search text box).  But I think the following graphical explanation might be of help to others.

The equivalent of this search in XP Search Companion (dog):

[image: XP Search Companion]

is this in Windows 7:

[image: Windows 7 Search]

Comment: Didn't work for me (with *.srt (plaintext subtitle files)).

Comment: "content:" is ignored... just make the test search the same string with and without "content:" and verify it...

Comment: @JeffRoe, I cannot get Windows to search inside `.sql` files. Did you actually get the expected results? I can’t help but notice that you cropped the screenshot just above the search results…

Comment: @Synetech: Yes, I definitely got the expected results.  Sorry, I'm not sure what would be different in your system that would prevent it from working.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried search the internet for the correct iFilter (for instance - http://www.ifilter.org/)?

If you have the right iFilter, Windows should be able to search and index its content.

Comment: do i need an "iFilter" for every file extension ?

Comment: Most likely yes - as each file extension assumes that the file contents would be specific for a particular extension.

Comment: Also - please review these two links - they have lots of content that should help you out:

http://www.microsoft.com/windows/products/winfamily/desktopsearch/technicalresources/filetypes.mspx

http://gallery.live.com/default.aspx?pl=6

Comment: And what if I don’t use the indexer, then what?

Answer (score 3):

In Windows XP you could add further (text) file types to be searched via the registry:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.dita\PersistentHandler]
@="{5e941d80-bf96-11cd-b579-08002b30bfeb}"
```

I'm not sure whether this works with Windows 7 as well.

Comment: This seems to do the trick in Windows 7. Unfortunately you have to create a file association for each and every damn file extension you want to search inside, but it at least it works and doesn’t require modifying the admin-level registry.

Comment: I don't understand this answer, is what's posted an example of adding the filetype .dita to windows search?

Comment: Yes, that is for a .dita extension.

Answer (score 2):

You could try using [Cygwin](http://cygwin.com/setup.exe) or grep version for Windows and searching *nix commands and search using the [grep](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html) utility.

[From Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html):

```
grep options pattern input_file_names
```

Using the Google gnuwin32 package, there is a grep version for Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Windows 7 SP1 ignores content: and contents: for me now, and it looks like the mechanism has changed: Now you type in what you want, and as soon as the search starts, a row at the bottom shows up with "Search again in:" Libraries, Computer, Custom, Firefox, and most importantly, **File Contents**. Click that and it restarts the search within files, even if the folder is unindexed.

Comment: on my machine `File Contents` is not given as an option

Comment: Are you using Win8? There, it's changed to where you have to click on the search tab, open Advanced Options, then File Contents.

Comment: Win 7 Home Premium 64bit SP1... strange its not there; commented to alert other confused readers (cos this issue really rattled me a lot and almost led to a BIG mistake sending passwords to a client in a file that wasn't being scanned as text)

Comment: Like the OP clearly explained, this does NOT work for certain file types.◔_◔