# Search content of files with unknown extension

Tags: search, windows-server-2008, file-extension

I have the problem that Windows Server 2008 does not seem to search through the content of files with a unknown extension (csv). How can I change this?
I had already installed the indexing service Role and changed its "Generation-Tab" Setting to "*Index files with unknown extension*" what does work in Windows XP but not yet in 2008. Do I have to restart the server first or is there a better way to say Windows that it also should search the content of unknown files?

Comment: Mind that indexing takes some time... after enabling indexing, it could take a few hours until it completes indexing those files.

Comment: Indexing is not activated because that is not necessary in XP. It is only a setting in the index service that is being applied whether the service is running or not. But while its working under XP it is not in Server 2008. But maybe i must restart the server after i installed the index service or there are other settings in 2008 for searching content of unknown filetypes?!

Comment: I don't know if Windows Server 2008 works the same as Windows 7 (in theory it's similar, but I never tried it), but if so, then this question might help you: http://superuser.com/questions/60173/how-to-search-inside-files-in-windows-7