# How to add multiple file extensions to the search inside feature in WIndows 7?

Tags: windows-7, search, windows-search

I know how to [add a single file extension to be searched inside](https://superuser.com/questions/60173/how-to-search-inside-files-in-windows-7), but I'd like to add a bunch of different extensions and avoid the tedious job of adding every single one.

Is there a command line tool or registry key I can use to accomplish this?

Answer (score 6):

You can search multiple file extensions in Windows Search with filters like this:

```
ext:.txt OR ext:.doc OR ext:.rtf
```