# Desktop search which indexes DjVu

Tags: windows, search, desktop-search, djvu

I happen to have large collection of ebooks, which are PDFs and DjVus (with text layer). I would like to be able to "search" the contents of my ebooks for phrases.
After some time spent on googling the issue, I found no software (except for discontinued Google Desktop Search) that is capable of reading text layer in .djvu files.

My needs are fairly simple: I don't need indexing emails, metadata in JPGs, etc. Just PDFs and DjVus and maybe plain text files. I need to have good control about what to index (Just one directory, and exactly nothing more).

I am using Windows.

Does anyone here knows any solution to this problem?

The programs I looked so far are:

- Beagle
- Copernic Desktop Search
- Terrier
- Google Desktop (discontinued)

Maybe the best advise is to stick to the Google Desktop Search? If so, can it be configured to index only specific directories?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider Archivarius 3000 at http://www.likasoft.com/

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: I tried it and can confirm, that this program indeed has support for .DjVu. Actually, it has more features and supports more formats I can imagine. Wow!

Answer (score 3):

If you use windows 7 you can install third-party IFilters for PDF and DJVU, and use build-in search as explained in [How to search inside files on Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/60173/how-to-search-inside-files-on-windows-7) I used the followinf IFilters:

- The IFilter for PDF from [SumatraPDF](http://blog.kowalczyk.info/software/sumatrapdf/free-pdf-reader.html) reader, please use [this build](http://blog.kowalczyk.info/software/sumatrapdf/free-pdf-reader.html) for 64bit version. Make sure you tick appropriate check mark in "Option" menu when installing SumatraPDF.
- The IFilter from [DjVu Shell Extension Pack](http://www.caminova.net/en/downloads/), which provides more useful feature to work with DJVU.

Comment: Good to know! Thank you. Unfortunately I use Windows XP, so this solution is not an option.

Comment: The DjVu Shell Extension Pack link is broken.