# How to find list of files which has particular keyword inside its content

Tags: windows-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to search inside files on Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/60173/how-to-search-inside-files-on-windows-7)

This was very easy in Windows XP. However I feel it pretty tedious to do this in Windows 7.

Using Windows 7 search bar, How can I list down the files whcih has particular keyword inside its contents.

Thank you for you time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the Search bar, type

```
contents: TYPEKEYWORD
```