# How do you search for files containing a word or phrase (XP's "dog" Search Companion) in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, search

Windows XP's Search Companion seems to be a lot more powerful than searching in Windows 7.

Particularly, I want to be able to search for filenames matching some pattern, containing a particular word.

For instance, how do I find files with the extension "sql" containing the word "view_customer"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To find files with the extendion "sql" containing the word "view_customer" in Windows 7, enter this in the Search text box:

```
content:view_customer *.sql
```

In pictures, the equivalent of this search in XP Search Companion (dog):
[image: XP Search Companion]

is this in Windows 7:
[image: Windows 7 Search]

This question is similar to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/60173/how-to-search-inside-files-on-windows-7) (though not exactly the same), but I wasn't allowed to add an answer to that because it is protected.

Comment: I'm kind of confused..  How is this any different than other answers on that other question?  Specifically http://superuser.com/a/180048/23133 tells you to use `content:` to filter by content, and putting in *.sql is the usual way to specify what files you want to search.  How is this new or different information?  BTW, you can use `type:` instead of specifying an `*.` style extension as well. ;)

Comment: The answer by Sean Sexton was pretty much what I was looking for, and I upvoted it.  But what I wanted to add was a nice graphical answer which translates what I'm used to doing in XP to what I need to do now in Windows 7.  Also, the answer I was looking for was 3rd down the list of a bunch of answers.  In light of all that, and the fact that I wasn't able to add an answer to the other question, I added this one.  I thought it would be a helpful contribution.  Also, the other question's accepted answer is not what I was looking for at all, so this didn't seem like a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

this works only on indexed files, so using an app like aborage Searcher works better also you could use the powershell: take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8153750/how-to-search-a-string-in-multiple-files-and-return-the-names-of-files-in-powers